# How to find the average of a column in Spark Dataframe without SQL queries, and use it as a filter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am a spark beginner and trying to solve a question from the Northwind Dataset where I need to list products whose prices are above the average price on a databricks notebook.

I tried this:

```
query6 = sparkDF7.select("ProductName","UnitPrice").agg({'UnitPrice':'mean'}).filter("UnitPrice>avg(UnitPrice)").show()
```

I've went through similar answers but they just won't work. Any help?

It throws me this error:

```
AnalysisException: 'Resolved attribute(s) UnitPrice#225 missing from avg(UnitPrice)#1350,avg(UnitPrice#225)#1355 in operator !Filter (UnitPrice#225 > avg(UnitPrice#225)#1355).;;\nProject [avg(UnitPrice)#1350]\n+- !Filter (UnitPrice#225 > avg(UnitPrice#225)#1355)\n   +- Aggregate [avg(UnitPrice#225) AS avg(UnitPrice)#1350, avg(UnitPrice#225) AS avg(UnitPrice#225)#1355]\n      +- Project [ProductName#221, UnitPrice#225]\n         +- Relation[ProductID#220,ProductName#221,SupplierID#222,CategoryID#223,QuantityPerUnit#224,UnitPrice#225,UnitsInStock#226,UnitsOnOrder#227,ReorderLevel#228,Discontinued#229] csv\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
spark_df7.selectExpr(
    "ProductName",
    "UnitPrice",
    "avg(UnitPrice) over(partition by 1) as avg_price"
).filter(
    "UnitPrice > avg_price"
).drop(
    "avg_price"
).show()
```

Just make sure that the DataFrame does not have duplicate products, which may skew the average price towards more frequently encountered products.

If you check results of `agg` method you will probably see a table of one row (since you have no `groupBy` clause) and one column (which is `avg(UnitPrice)` as `Project` statement in the Exception suggests).

Comment: The problem is in the `avg(UnitPrice) over(partition by 1) as avg_price` line. It can't resolve that. Do i need to add an `avg(UnitPrice)` column? If yes, then how?

Comment: Finally got possibility to test and fix errors. I've edited my answer. This should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I think your "UnitPrice" is not in the DataFrame generated out of `agg` so the `filter` can't resolve it.

Try use `window` instead.